# insert query showing error syntax error while inserting small date time value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to insert  a record with small date time .createddate is small date time data type. error - "Incorrect syntax near '2017-10-06 16:43:10'.". data type - smalldatetime

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]
           ([UserID]
           ,[FullName]
           ,[Username]
           ,[Password]
           ,[City]
           ,[Phone]
           ,[Status]
           ,[CreatedDate])
     VALUES
           (2
           ,'krisha mohan'
           ,'krishna'
           ,'krishna@123'
           ,'hyderabad'
           ,'868613986'
           ,1
           ,'2017-10-06 16:43:10'
GO
```

Comment: You are missing a closing paren on the `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing closing parenthesis ")" just before the Go statement.

here is your query will look like.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]
       ([UserID]
       ,[FullName]
       ,[Username]
       ,[Password]
       ,[City]
       ,[Phone]
       ,[Status]
       ,[CreatedDate])
 VALUES
       (2
       ,'krisha mohan'
       ,'krishna'
       ,'krishna@123'
       ,'hyderabad'
       ,'868613986'
       ,1
       ,'2017-10-06 16:43:10'
       )
GO
```